# Prevent Inserting same combination of Component and template :

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

In a page when we will click the **component Presentation tab** we can see the component and template listed there.On clicking of **Insert** button just below that, it will open another window "**Insert component presentation**" there also we will have **Insert** and close button.So now what i need to do While inserting i need to check whether the combination of **selected Component and Template** is already present there on page or not. If yes then it should prevent inserting the same with a  popup like "this combination is already present, select other componet". 
Any idea how can i proceed. How can i trigger a Javascript on the **Insert** button?

**EDIT:**

When i am subscrbing it to Page i am getting erro.My code :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Text;
using Tridion.ContentManager.Extensibility.Events;
using Tridion.ContentManager.Extensibility;
using Tridion.ContentManager.ContentManagement;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;




namespace MyEventHandlers
{
[TcmExtension("MyEventHandlerExtension")]

public class MyEventHandler : TcmExtension 
{
    public MyEventHandler()
{
  Subscribe();
}

public void Subscribe()
{
    EventSystem.Subscribe<Page, SaveEventArgs>(SaveBtnInitiated, EventPhases.Initiated);

}

private void SaveBtnInitiated(Page subject, SaveEventArgs args, EventPhases phase)
{

    try
    {
        List<string> allcplist = new List<string>();
        List<string> allcplist = new List<string>();
        foreach (ComponentPresentation cp in subject.ComponentPresentations)
        {
            allcplist.Add(cp.Component.Id + "," + cp.ComponentTemplate.Id);   
        }
        List<string> uniquecplist = allcplist.Distinct().ToList();
        if (allcplist.Count != uniquecplist.Count)
        {
            subject.Checkin(false);
            throw new Exception("Page has duplicate component presentation");

    }
    catch(Exception)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you check-in the page? When you run this handler on the initiated phase throwing an exception will cancel the operation.
Besides that you cancel the exception by catching it and not doing anything.

Comment: I removed check-in and used save . and its working . thank u arjen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you subscribing to the Component? I think it should be the Page. Then you can walk through the `ComponentPresentations` property.

Code to go through the Component Presentations and throw an exception when duplicate presentations are found:

```C#
foreach (var cpA in subject.ComponentPresentations)
{
    if (subject.ComponentPresentations.Where(cpB => ComponentPresentationsAreEqual(cpA, cpB)).ToList().Count() > 2)
    {
        throw new DuplicateComponentPresentationsEmbeddedOnPageException();
    }
}
```

And the function to include cpB in the list when it is equal to cpA:

```C#
function ComponentPresentationsAreEqual(ComponentPresentation cpA, ComponentPresentation cpB)
{
    return cpA.Component.Id == cpB.Component.Id && cpA.ComponentTemplate.Id == cpB.ComponentTemplate.Id;
}
```

Comment: thank you arjen... i am getting error when i am subcribing to page.

Comment: What's the error?
`EventSystem.Subscribe<Page, SaveEventArgs>(PageIsSaved, EventPhases.Initiated);`
`static void PageIsSaved(Page subject, SaveEventArgs eventArgs, EventPhases phase)`

Comment: Actually i was using "using System.Web.UI" that is why it was showing that error.

Answer (score 4):

You can implement this in an event handler that is subscribed to the Page Save event and the Initiated phase. When there is a duplicate Component Presentation you can cancel the Save by throwing an exception. The message will be shown in the Message Center in the TCM Explorer.

Comment: Thank you Arjen for you response... can you explain how can i subscribe event handler to the page save event.

Comment: There is an article about the 2011 event system on SDL Tridion World: http://sdltridionworld.com/articles/sdltridion2011/sdltridion2011eventsystem.aspx and an example event system with a lot of useful information can also be found there http://sdltridionworld.com/community/2011_extensions/rapideditorialinterface.aspx

Comment: hi Bart, thanks for your time. but the prob is tht i am not able to accesss the PDF provided in the below link. Kindly clear my doubt that can we trigger a javascript on the Insert button which will check for the duplicat component while inserting.Because i need to check whether user is selecting same combination or not "**while Inserting only**"

Comment: If you want to do it while inserting, it must be via a CME extension. Fire up your favorite JS console and start debugging until you understand what event or command is fired when the user adds a new component presentation - once you find it, then find a way to subscribe to the same event and interfere with the results.

Comment: thanks Nuno.. i found the event fired when a user is selecting insert.. but how can i subscribe the same event and interface with the result...

Comment: Be aware that the CME extension approach would not prevent anyone to create a page with duplicate component presentations programmatically.

Comment: @Arjen Stobbe I am using event handler on the Save event. i have used like this `public void Subscribe() { `EventSystem.Subscribe<Component, SaveEventArgs>``(SaveBtnInitiated, EventPhases.Initiated); `} private void `SaveBtnInitiated(Component save, SaveEventArgs args, `EventPhases phase)` { `try {       } catch(Exception) { } }` i need your help in code part just for a start how can i check for dulpicate component presentation .

Answer (score 0):

**I got my Result with this code Thanks to  @Arjen Stobbe**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Text;
using Tridion.ContentManager.Extensibility.Events;
using Tridion.ContentManager.Extensibility;
using Tridion.ContentManager.ContentManagement;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;




namespace MyEventHandlers
{
[TcmExtension("MyEventHandlerExtension")]

public class MyEventHandler : TcmExtension 
{
    public MyEventHandler()
{
  Subscribe();
}

public void Subscribe()
{
    EventSystem.Subscribe<Page, SaveEventArgs>(SaveBtnInitiated, EventPhases.Initiated);

}

private void SaveBtnInitiated(Page subject, SaveEventArgs args, EventPhases phase)
{

    try
    {
        List<string> allcplist = new List<string>();
        List<string> allcplist = new List<string>();
        foreach (ComponentPresentation cp in subject.ComponentPresentations)
        {
            allcplist.Add(cp.Component.Id + "," + cp.ComponentTemplate.Id);   
        }
        List<string> uniquecplist = allcplist.Distinct().ToList();
        if (allcplist.Count != uniquecplist.Count)
        {
            subject.Save(false);
            throw new Exception("Page has duplicate component presentation");

    }
    catch(Exception)
    {

    }
}
```

But i am not deleting the duplicate CP present on the page. Do i need to add,

```
for each()
```

inside

```
if (allcplist.Count != uniquecplist.Count)
{
}
```

Comment: Maybe ask this as a separate question--it's harder to respond in comments and also because  the original questions already has an answer. :-)